# XPathSelectElement returns null

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xpath

This is my XPath:

```
./trade/financeLeg/paymentDates/paymentDate[1]
```

and this is my xml file:

```
<dataDocument>
   <trade>
        <underlyingSymbol />
        <quantity />
        <avgPrice />
        <notional />
        <effectiveDate />
        <lookBack>0</lookBack>
        <expirationDate />
        <broker>Select</broker>
        <exchange />
        <equityLeg>
          <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
          <paymentDates>
            <paymentDate />
          </paymentDates>
          <currency>USD</currency>
        </equityLeg>
        <financeLeg>
          <resetDates>
            <resetDate />
          </resetDates>
          <interestRate>0.00</interestRate>
          <spread>0</spread>
          <dayCount>ACT/360</dayCount>
          <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
          <paymentDates>
            <paymentDate />
          </paymentDates>
          <currency>USD</currency>
          <interestRateBenchMark>Select</interestRateBenchMark>
          <marginCollateral>0.00</marginCollateral>
        </financeLeg>
        <dividendLeg>
          <paymentDate />
          <currency>USD</currency>
          <dividedRate>0.00</dividedRate>
          <frequency>Monthly</frequency>
        </dividendLeg>
   </trade>
 </dataDocument>
```

when I use the XPath on **XPathSelectElement** it returns 'null', I realize that this might be due to the tag being empty. But what is the best way to get the element with Xpath?

Comment: What if you start your XPath with `.//` instead of `./`?

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that this was because my XML saved the empty node as  after I changed it to , I was able to make the xpath work

Answer (score 0):

/ in xpath means start finding from the root
if you use /, you can try /dataDocument/trade/financeLeg/paymentDates/paymentDate[1]

I believe that you want to use
//trade/financeLeg/paymentDates/paymentDate[1]

Comment: Do you mean that the xpath expression is invalid? or you get null? Based on the xml you provide, it should return null as there is no value

Comment: I want to set the value of this node, and as far as I know XPathSelectElement returns the element. I want to retrieve this element and then update its value